# Used port not showing up in netstat -a result

Tags: networking, windows-7, activemq-classic, netstat

This issues started recently when I am trying to start active-mq (which by default starts on port 61616). But suddenly it stopped coming up with JVM_BIND issue on that port. The problem did not go away even after restarting the computer.

Main problem is that 
netstat -a command on Windows 7, does not show that 61616 is consumed. But when I wrote a simple Java program to bind a socket to that port, I wasn't certainly able to!

I eventually started active-mq by moving to a different port. But, can anybody please help me find why all the ports are not showing up in netstat -a result? Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Don't use ephemeral ports:
http://www.ncftp.com/ncftpd/doc/misc/ephemeral_ports.html

[What is the largest TCP/IP network port number allowable for IPv4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113224/what-is-the-largest-tcp-ip-network-port-number-allowable-for-ipv4)

Comment: Understand, but the number I am using to get it to work now is 61000! It works. Also, 61616 did work (this is the default for active-mq) the very first time I used it on my computer two days ago. Can't explain that.

Comment: This is not an issue here I believe, I have same problem as author of this post.