# what is the range of apache tomcat listener ports?

Tags: tomcat

I am aware of using netstat cmd in unix to find out the ports that are in use. But I am wondering how to determine the range of available apache tomcat listener ports to deploy an HTTP web application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat will run on whatever port you set it to run on. The max port number is 65535. Normal http ports are 80 and 8080.

To change your Tomcat port see this answer: [How to change tomcat port number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415578/how-to-change-tomcat-port-number)

For more on port numbers see: [What is the largest TCP/IP network port number allowable for IPv4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113224/what-is-the-largest-tcp-ip-network-port-number-allowable-for-ipv4)